# How can I fix this error and upload files?

Tags: 8, files, webforms

I have a simple form with just a field to upload a file on a Drupal 8 site using the Webform module 6.0.1. If I test the form using webforms test tool, the file gets uploaded fine, it displays the loading icon for couple seconds and its ready to upload, but if I try the same in a page with the form embedded as a block, I can not upload the file it will always show me the following message if I try to submit the form, no matter how long I wait.

```
"File upload in progress. Uploaded file may be lost. Do you want to continue?"
```

Just for testing, I increased the max upload file to 2GB and the file I'm uploading is just 5kb. All the .js libraries I can think of are on my template.info.yml file. (core/drupal, core/jquery, core/drupal.ajax) The private folder has been set up in my settings.php and has the permissions set correctly the .htaccess file is also set as recommended for Drupal. I have try to upload the files in the public folder just as desperation but I get the same error

Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: Looks like a known issue with the module: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3060531. Reading the issue it sounds like the problem is going to be something in your custom theme

Comment: Does the problem persist if you switch the theme? Maybe Bartik?

Comment: Thanks Clive, I saw that issue but unfortunately I could not fix it following those instructions. Yes for sure is something happening on my theme because if I use Bartik the problem is not there any more. Any recommendations on how to approach  this issue and try to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out what the problem was. I'm posting the solution for my case just in case someone has the same problem.
My problem was that I had change the submit button ID in the input.html.twig file. I replaced it to the original and it works fine.